# How to change the option text in php?

Tags: php, mysql, database, admin

I tried to build an admin page. The admin will fill a form to add new product in the database and display it in the shop website. The problem is when I tried to select a gender from the dropbox, the new product doesn't add in the product table in the database as you can see below: (I want to select gender such as Boys)

The Admin Page and database result:

[image]

The code I used:

```
$host = "";
                $userMS = "";
                $passwordMS = "";
                $connection = mysql_connect($host,$userMS,$passwordMS) or die("Couldn't  connect:".mysql_error());
                $database = "projectDataBase";
                $db = mysql_select_db($database,$connection) or die("Couldn't select database");

            if (isset($_POST['sAddProduct']))
            {

                    addNewProduct();
            }else if(isset($_POST['delete']))
            {
            $Product_ID=$_POST['Product_ID'];
            $mysqlquery="delete  from Product where Product_ID= ".$Product_ID."";
            mysql_query($mysqlquery);
                    echo "Deleted successfully";
                    echo("<FORM><INPUT Type='button' VALUE='Back' onClick='history.go(-1);return true;'></FORM>");
            }else{
                    showForm();
            }               


            // add new product
            function addNewProduct()
            {
            $ProductName = $_POST['Product_Name'];
            $ProductPrice = $_POST['Price'];
            $Gender = $_POST['Gender_ID'];


            //database query to add product
            $insertStringProduct = "INSERT into Product(Product_Name, Price,Gender_ID)
            VALUE('$ProductName', '$ProductPrice', '$Gender')";
            $result = mysql_query($insertStringProduct);



            echo ("<p1>Product added Successfully</p1>");
            echo("<FORM><INPUT Type='button' VALUE='Back' onClick='history.go(-1);return true;'></FORM>");
}



  //function for the form page     
            function showForm()
                    {       
                        //First form for adding new product
                        $self = htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
                                echo("<form action = '$self' method='POST'>
                                <fieldset>
                                        <legend>Adding New Product</legend>
                                        Product Name: <input name='Product_Name' type='text' size = '40'>
                                        <br /><br />
                                        Price: <input name='Price' type='text' size = '20'><br><br /> 


                                        Gender: 
                            <select name='Gender_Description'>
                            <option value = '%'> <-- select--></option>");

                            $dbQuary = " SELECT DISTINCT Gender_Description from Gender";
                            $result = mysql_query($dbQuary);

                            while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
                                echo("<option value ='$row[0]'> $row[0]</option>");
                            }
                            echo("
                            </select>


                    <br/><br/>
                                        <input type='submit' name='sAddProduct' value = 'Add'/>
                                        <input type='reset' value='Clear' />
                                </fieldset>

                                </form>");


    }
```

The result ( nothing added)

However, when I change the code to

```
 Gender: 
                            <select name='Gender_ID'>
                            <option value = '%'> <-- select--></option>");

                            $dbQuary = " SELECT DISTINCT Gender_ID from Gender";
                            $result = mysql_query($dbQuary);
```

It's working

[image]

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You already described how you changed the code to get it to work. So what exactly is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `addNewProduct` you are expecting `$_POST['Gender_ID']` to be set. So of course, `<select name='Gender_Description'>` would not work, because `Gender_Description != Gender_ID`. That's also why it does work when you change it.

I'm assuming what you want to achive is to display the gender description, and it still to work. For that, you need both the id and the description:

```
$dbQuary = " SELECT DISTINCT Gender_ID, Gender_Description from Gender";
$result = mysql_query($dbQuary);

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
    echo("<option value ='$row[0]'> $row[1]</option>");
}
```

**Security**

Your code is **extremely unsafe**. You are using `mysql_*` which is deprecated since 2013, and you are not sanitizing the input in any way, so your code is open to SQL injection (which is possibly in all kinds of queries; insert, update, delete, etc, and allows for data leaks, DOS, and possibly code execution and deletion/changing of data). The preferred way to prevent this are prepared statements (either using `mysqli_*` or `PDO`). They are not difficult to use, and the resulting code is also nicer.

Answer (score 0):

You are not concatenating values as it should

Change

`echo("<option value ='$row[0]'> $row[0]</option>");`

to

`echo("<option value =". '$row[0]' . "> ". $row[0]. "</option>");`

OR

`echo("<option value ='{$row[0]}'> {$row[0]}</option>");`

EDIT:

Change your `While-loop`
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_BOTH)) {
          `echo("<option value ='{$row['gender_id']}'> {$row['gender_description']}</option>");`
       }

This will generate a Select list showing the Gender Description and and values will be numeric(of database)

Comment: still not working. I want to display the text in dropbox filed such as "Boys and Girls". when I use the Gender_ID and the dropbox shows number of ID that's working. I hope you understand me.  Cheers!

Comment: Could I use a if statement to change the number to text or that's not working ?

Comment: I dont understand you ... 
show me your Gender table

Comment: This is the Gender table : http://www.ya-techno.com/up/uploads/1429517742881.png    And this is the Product table : http://www.ya-techno.com/up/uploads/1429517744622.png